# Disabling form validation

Tags: angularjs

`Angularjs` is running my forms through the `FormController` (eg tracking pristine, dirty, etc).  I don't need this functionality; I'm sure it's adding overhead to my `$digests`.

How can I shut it off?

Comment: Roy - I'm with you on this.  I'd love to be able to disable form validation in Angular.  I find myself constantly fighting it.  Yes, it's great that it's available, but we need an "ng-dont-validate" option on forms in case we have our own methodology.

Comment: Actually, I finally stumbled across a solution.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AFAIK there is no simple switch to turn off AngularJS validation. Actually most of the validation happens in the `NgModelController` and input directives - basically code in the [input.js file](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/input.js). So, to get rid of the built-in validation you would have to re-develop code from this file (plus some others, like select).

Did you identify validation code as a performance bottleneck in your application?

Comment: Thx Pawel, no I have not found a slowdown but my forms are small.  The long and short of it is that it's unnecessary overhead - it does DOM manip and adds to the weight of the digest.  I've asked about Angular's form validation @ meetups and my feeling was that not many people leverage it, so I would have expected a way to skip it.

Comment: Hmm, interesting remark of people not using form validation... From what I saw it used quite often...

Comment: @RoyTruelove: I think not too many people *know* it's there to leverage it.  That said: [FORK THAT MOTHER AND MAKE IT BETTER!](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/)... then submit a pull request.

Comment: Considering it if I trusted my js skills enough :)

Answer (score 9):

UPDATE : This does NOT work ... well at least not in a way you'd like it to.  Adding ng-non-bindable to the form or any input breaks ALL binding.  So, your ng-model in the inputs won't work anymore. Sorry ....

ng-non-bindable is the solution to this problem.

It will prevent AngularJS from seeing the form as a directive. This will make AngularJS ignore the entire form:

```
<form name="inviteContactForm" ng-non-bindable>
```

This will make AngularJS ignore one part of a form:

```
<input type="email" name="email" ng-non-bindable>
```

You can read a bit about my whining on this issue here. http://calendee.com/preventing-angularjs-from-hijacking-forms/

Comment: Justin, have you managed how to disable default from processing in anularJS?

Comment: @kay A few days ago, I rewrote AngularJS validation.  It was terrible.  Now, I've come to terms with AngularJS validation.  I just wrote a custom directive to make it work the way I like.  http://calendee.com/angularjs-validate-on-timeout/

Comment: @FrankTudor Validation in the newest releases of angular is much improved since I posted all this.  You might want to skip that custom directive of mine.  See this post for better info on the new ngMessages. https://calendee.com/2014/12/26/validation-in-ionic-framework-apps-with-ngmessages/

Answer (score 2):

Internally Angular creates *factories* out of *directives* by adding the *Directive* suffix to the directive name. So you can replace the validation and input directive factories with no-operational ones.

```
var noopDirective = function() { return function () {}; };
angular.module('myModule')
    .factory('requiredDirective', noopDirective)
    .factory('ngRequiredDirective', noopDirective)
    .factory('inputDirective', noopDirective)
    .factory('textareaDirective', noopDirective); // etc...
```

Comment: That certainly does the trick.  But unfortunately, you lose all ngModel binding then.  The trick here is to KEEP model binding but lose all the other stuff.

Comment: Yes you are right, I did it in a project but only for `ngRequire`, so I extrapolated. After looking at the "source":https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/input.js#L1004 you can't separate the validity on an `ngInput` from the `ngModel`, because it's part of the ngModel. I guess another option is to surgically set the methods to `noop`, ugh!

Answer (score 2):

A colleague suggested a nifty way of disabling validators. Here's an implementation:

```
<input type="radio" name="enableValidation" ng-model="$ctrl.validationEnabled" ng-value="true" />Enabled
<input type="radio" name="enableValidation" ng-model="$ctrl.validationEnabled" ng-value="false" />Disabled

<input type="number" 
       name="age" 
       ng-model="$ctrl.age" 
       min="20" 
       disable-validation="!$ctrl.validationEnabled" />
```

When `disable-validation` is true, then all validation rules automatically passes.

```
function disableValidation(scope, elem, attrs, ngModelController) {

  function wrapOriginalValidators() {
    var originalValidators = angular.copy(ngModelController.$validators);
    Object.keys(originalValidators).forEach(function(key) {
      ngModelController.$validators[key] = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        return scope.$eval(attrs.disableValidation) || originalValidators[key](modelValue, viewValue);
      }
    });
  }

  function watchDisableCriteria() {
    scope.$watch(attrs.disableValidation, function() {
      // trigger validation
      var originalViewValue = ngModelController.$viewValue;
      scope.$applyAsync(function() {
        ngModelController.$setViewValue('');
      });
      scope.$applyAsync(function() {
        ngModelController.$setViewValue(originalViewValue);
      });
    });
  }

  wrapOriginalValidators();
  watchDisableCriteria();

}

angular.module('app', [])
  .directive('disableValidation', function() {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: disableValidation
    };
  });
```

Obviously, you'd not use this for performance reasons, but when you
need to dynamically enable or disable validations.

Sample: https://plnkr.co/edit/EM1tGb

Comment: I had a look at this but it seems to break validation on inputs that use ng-required, any reason for this? I modified your plnkr for to show what I mean: https://plnkr.co/edit/DI9XSgVQoDmik2baR7ZN

Answer (score 2):

Similar to previous answer from @Chui Tey, having a directive that requires 'ngModel'. This is what I did
for disabling validations in runtime:

```
//disabling all validators
forEach(ngModelController.$validators, function(validator, validatorName){
  ngModelController.$setValidity(validatorName, true);//mark invalid as valid
  var originalValidator = ngModelController.$validators[validatorName]; //we save the original validator for being able to restore it in future
  ngModelController.$validators[validatorName] = _.wrap(true);//overwrite the validator 
  ngModelController.$validators[validatorName].originalValidator = originalValidator;
});

//for restoring validations    
forEach(ngModelController.$validators, function(validator, validatorName){             
  if(ngModelController.$validators[validatorName].originalValidator){
    ngModelController.$validators[validatorName] = ngModelController.$validators[validatorName].originalValidator;
  }
});
ngModelController.$validate(); //triger validations
```