# AngularJS Stop blocking form

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm relatively new to AngularJS and I am trying to sumbit a regular form. I have basic form that looks like this:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
input type="text" class="title span5" name="post_title" placeholder="A catchy title here..." value="" />

<input type="file" name="post_image" />

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Create Post" />
</form>
```

But I noticed that AngularJS adds its own values to the form.

```
<form method="post" enctpye="multipart/form-data" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
```

And I am ununable to submit the form. How can I disable the automatic validation that Angular JS is adding to the app?

Comment: You're not ending your form element.

Comment: Corrected the example, but thats not it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoted from the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aform):

> For this reason, Angular prevents the default action (form submission to the server) unless the  element has an action attribute specified.

IMHO, you should read the doc to gain some general understanding of single page application, and the reason why angular's preventing the default behavior.

Comment: I just add the current url to each action attribute of the form

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE : This does NOT work** ... well at least not in a way you'd like it to.  Adding ng-non-bindable to the form or any input breaks ALL binding.  So, your ng-model in the inputs won't work anymore.

---

ng-non-bindable is possibly your best choice.  It will prevent AngularJS from doing ANY validation.  So, you'll be responsible for showing invalid and checking validity.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19387233/75644